# Swift Anchor two buttons on bottom, one on left and one on right

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I need to add two buttons programmatically to an existing view, I need one button on bottom left and one on bottom right. I'm able to add the right one, but I don't know how can I add the left one.
Below my code that work for the right button. Ho can I add the other button on the left side?

```
   private func constrainFloatingButtonToWindow() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }),
            let floatingButton = self.floatingButton else { return }
        keyWindow.addSubview(floatingButton)
        keyWindow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: floatingButton.trailingAnchor,
                                            constant: self.trailingValue).isActive = true
        keyWindow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: floatingButton.bottomAnchor,
                                          constant: self.trailingValue).isActive = true
        floatingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:
            DataTableViewController.buttonWidth).isActive = true
        floatingButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:
            DataTableViewController.buttonHeight).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this constraints:

```
yourView.addSubview(yourButton)
yourButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
yourButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
yourButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // sostituisci il valore con quelli tuoi
yourButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

[image]